# Full page background in portrait mode

Tags: css, cordova

I am using this code to make the background fill the entire phone page:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It's working fine in Ripple Emulator in both orientations (portrait and landscape.) The problem arises when I run it on my real phone; it only works in landscape. In portrait mode most of the page is white.

Why is that? Does it have something to do with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `cover`, using `100% 100%;` is a more reliable option when it comes to orientation of devices,

See demo here in fiddle  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u7p9m/)

```
html { 
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ-FZuItoVKah_RGHbFqQvwmvDIDuH1m7D1EaogdgaolNs1BQK0) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size:  100% 100%;
  background-size:  100% 100%;
}
```

Additionally, use `height: 100%;` in your `html` for better compatibility!

Comment: but that will stretch the image in portrait mode